Failing to install ROS raspberry pi4
Following this tutorial I keep getting the following error.
sudo apt install ros-iron-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-iron-ros-base

I tried this on kernel version linux-image-5.15.0-1055-raspi, linux-image-5.15.0-1046-raspi, and linux-image-5.15.0-1054-raspi.
I have installed ros iron onto raspberry pi 4's in the past without issue so I'm not sure if I have made a mistake or if something broke somewhere.
I would like to note that I can install ros-dev-tools.

I would guess based on kernel names you are installing PiOS? Could you try installing it on Ubuntu 22.04. or  Ubuntu 24.04. LTS server? I have made good experience with it and Pi Imager let's you choose it under General Purpose OS.

Which is what ros.org also recommends.

@Scoeerg
I used Pi Imager. When using lsb_release -a I get the following
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy


https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428793/inconsistent-situation-after-upgrade-to-22-04-lts-from-20-04-lts Does this work for you?

Sadly that did not solve the problem. I was getting Ubuntu 22.04 before and am still getting it now.

I'm not sure what fixed it but reflashing the pi it was fixed. The only thing I believe I changed was a username and password in pi-imager rather than the default ubuntu / ubuntu.
